# I would like to average the first n columns based on duplicate values of the n+1th column

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

I have a matrix with duplicate numbers in one of the columns. I would like to average the rows with duplicate numbers. For example, I have duplicate values in a matrix `A` in column 3:

```
A =   
    1         2         1
    4         4         2
    5         4         2
    4         5         2
    5         5         3
    10        3         3
```

I would like to get

```
B =
    1         2         1
    4.3333    4.3333    2.0000
    7.5000    4.0000    3.0000
```

where each row is the average values of the duplicate rows of column 3.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try? Is there something wrong with `for` loop (other than that it may be done more efficiently)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one-liner averages all rows with duplicate values in column `N`.

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)mean(A(A(:, N)==x,:),1), unique(A(:, N)), 'Uniform', 0))
```

#### Example

Let's follow your example and average all lines with duplicates in column 3:

```
A = [1 2 1; 4 4 2; 5 4 2; 4 5 2; 5 5 3; 10 3 3];
N = 3;
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)mean(A(A(:, N)==x,:),1), unique(A(:,N)), 'Uniform', 0))
```

The result is:

```
B =
    1.0000   2.0000   1.0000
    4.3333   4.3333   2.0000
    7.5000   4.0000   3.0000
```

Comment: Thank you very much EitanT. I feel a little stupid. This works great for me